# How to listen for new YouTube videos?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube, youtube-api, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on firebase project that should provide a search for a certain YouTube channel.

With the YouTube API I can index available videos from this channel.

**My question is:**

What is the best way to index newly created videos? Is there some kind of event/trigger/notification I can hook in with google cloud functions? If possible, I want to avoid polling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a way to subscribe for notifications ( newly created videos ). The Youtube API provides a way to do so with a [PubSubHubbub](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) server ( and no, that is not a typo ).

> Your PubSubHubbub callback server receives Atom feed notifications when a channel does any of the following activities:
>
> - uploads a video
> - updates a video's title
> - updates a video's description

Comment: yeah looks like this is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting my answer if this has solved your question.This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I know. But I need additional help. I don't fully understand now how I can trigger a cloud function.

Comment: Could you provide more information with regards to the general architecture of your application? For instance, do you have a separate backend server that would be making use of pubsubhubbub, eventually calling GCF whenever changes occur, or are you looking to make use of pubsubhubbub within GCF?

Comment: I've a firebase project with GCF. I don't plan with an extra backend server if it's not necessary. Is it possible to use pubsubhubbub within GCF? The problem is I don't know a thing about pubsub and cloud messaging.

Comment: Sorry that it took some time to get into it. In the end I only need an Https Cloud function which need to do 2 things. 1. Echo the hub.challenge query parameter to confirm the subscription. 2. Handle the incoming xml.